# Help with drawing the following circuit diagram

Tags: circuitikz, width, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I'm just learning how to use circuitikz and I'm trying to draw the following circuit diagram

[image]

Here's what I've got so far

[image]

```
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) node[ocirc,ground]{$-m$}
  to[short] (1,0)
  to[R=$text$] (2,0) 
  to[short] (3,0)
  to[R=$text$] (4,0) 
  to[short] (5,0)
  to[R=$\ldots$] (6,0)
  to[short] (7,0)
  to[R=$text$] (8,0) 
  to[short] (9,0)
  to[R=$text$] (10,0) 
  to[short] (11,0)
  to[R=$\ldots$] (12,0)
  to[short] (13,0)
  to[R=$text$] (14,0) 
  to[short] (15,0)
  to[R=$text$] (16,0) 
  to[short] (17,0)
  to[short] (17,2) 
  to[V=$1V$] (0,2)
  to[short] (0,2)
  to[short] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
```

I'd really appreciate some help to resolve the following issues:

1. Adding nodes between the resistors with labels.
2. Making the whole thing fit on the page!
3. Having an ellipsis as the node (rather than having a resistor there like I do now)
4. Putting the leftmost label on the left rather than where it falls now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) node[left=1mm] {$n$}     
                to [R=$+e_x-$,*-*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$-n+1$}
                to [R=$+e_x-$, -*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$-n+2$} coordinate[right=15mm]  (aux1)
      (aux1) node[below=3mm] {$-1$}
                to [R=$+e_x-$,*-*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$0$}
                to [R=$+e_x-$, -*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$1$}    coordinate[right=15mm]  (aux2)
      (aux2) node[below=3mm] {$n-2$}
                to [R=$+e_x-$,*-*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$n-1$}
                to [R=$+e_x-$, -*]  ++ (1.5,0) node[below=3mm] {$n$}    coordinate[above=15mm]  (aux3)
%
      (0,0) -- ++ (0,1.5)
            to [battery2, l=$+e_x-$,invert]   (aux3) -- ++ (0,-1.5)
      (0,0) -- ++ (0,-0.5) node [ground] {};
\path   (aux1) -- node {\huge$\dots$}    ++  (-1.5,0)
        (aux2) -- node {\huge$\dots$}    ++  (-1.5,0);
   \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

labels of resistors and battery in your sketch are not well readable. i read them as `+e_x-`, but i'm not sure in this. however you can easy change them to what you like to have.

Answer (score 1):

`nodes` can be placed at coordinates between which resistors are drawn. Now node shape, label and placement of the label can be controlled.

The diagram can be scaled with the `scale=` option. Note that `transform shape` is also used along with it. Remove it and see what it is doing. ;)

See the example below:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{elps/.style={fill,scale=0.5,ellipse, text width=1pt,text height=3pt}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=0.9cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.5,transform shape]
  \draw (0,0) node[ground]{};
  \draw (0,0) node[elps,label={[left=3mm]$-m$}]{}
  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$-m+1$}]{}
  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$-m+2$}]{}
  to[R=$\ldots$] ++(2,0)node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$1$}]{}

  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$0$}]{}
  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$-1$}]{}
  to[R=$\ldots$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$m-2$}]{}

  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$m-1$}]{}
  to[R=$text$] ++(2,0) node[elps,label={[below=3mm]$m$}]{}

  to[short] ++(0,2) 
  to[V=$1V$] (0,2)
  to[short] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I have also replaced few absolute coordinates with relative coordinates using `++(x,y)`; removed few unwanted `short`s and changed the `bipoles` length.

Comment: This is great thanks so much! The only thing I wonder about is whether it's possible to have the ellipsis in place of the resistor in the circuit? It's not a big deal but is it possible? :)

Comment: @jason it is possible. Using the library `decorations.markings` is an option.